# PHP echo'ed out form with two fields, submit focus not changing to just hit enter on keyboard?

Tags: php, forms

I have site where there is a form begin created by php:

```
echo "<form width='300px' action='results.php' method='post'>";
 echo "<fieldset>";
 echo "<legend>Find Resources!</legend>";
 echo "<label for='euoff'>Quick List of Services</label><br />";
      echo "<select name='offering' id='euoff'>";
      echo "<option value=''>--Select One--</option>";
        foreach ($values as $eu){
            echo "<option class='$reg' value='$eu[0]'>$eu[1]</option>";
        }
     echo "</select>";
 echo "<input type='submit' class='btn' name='submit' value='GO' />";
 echo "</fieldset>";
  echo "<fieldset>";
 echo "<legend>Quick Resource Search</legend>";
 echo "<label for='soff'>Enter your search term below.</label><br />";
      echo "<input class='align-left' name='soffering' type='text' size='50' maxlength='25' id='soff' />";
 echo "<input type='submit' class='btn' name='ssubmit' value='GO' />";
 echo "</fieldset>";
 echo "</form>";
 echo "</div>";
```

When a user selects an item from the Select list they have to click the GO button with the mouse, not sure why... Any suggestions? Also, if a user enters data in the second input - "soffering" - they have to click GO as enter on the keyboard is not triggering the second submit (ssubmit) button.

Anyone have an answer to why? Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use `echo` to write HTML in PHP. Just do `?>` and write HTML until you have to use PHP, by which time you write `<?php` again.

Comment: @Jack Thanks for the tip :) I'll update the code. It's terrible now.

Comment: @Jack That's entirely subjective... One method is not better than the other, the choice is best made by what is most readable, extensible, or usable for the given project and/or context.

Comment: @orourkek I updated the code from what it was, it is more readable for me now. Glad to hear opinions though!

Comment: @orourkek Are you saying that using `echo` is more readable in this instance? besides, I don't see a need to burden the VM with parsing and executing additional tokens if it can just skip sections of verbatim HTML.

Comment: @Jack I only commented because of your wording: "Please don't use echo to write HTML in PHP." This clearly isn't talking about just this case, as in your second comment. I agree that in this case using echo might not be as readable, but there is no "standard" for html output beyond workplace/personal standards.

Comment: @orourkek Just like how there's no standard on how to make phone calls on your mobile phone, but keeping your phone plugged into the wall socket does limit your options :) in this case, many editors have some form of HTML validation, folding and tag matching which are rendered useless when using `echo`, same goes for JavaScript; together with the nightmare of quoting and escaping ... that's just bad common sense, except in case of exceptions :)

Comment: @Jack I'm sorry but arguing the point with just "Some people use in-editor validation" is not nearly enough of a reason. Using echo isn't comparable to keeping the phone plugged into the wall at all... If, like most of the coding world, you have job-specific coding standards, then all this goes out the window. My current and three previous jobs all used echo for html output simply to avoid having the code riddled with php tags (which is annoying). There is no "common sense" or anything close to a standard in this respect, it's just whatever works in the situation, as I've stated from the start

Comment: I would have to add to this conversation... it works either way, but readability wise, for what I have done, using Jack's suggestion cleaned up the page I have inherited quite a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that what you want is for the ENTER/RETURN key to submit the form while a `<select>` is focused. This is not possible, since the ENTER/RETURN key is used to select an option when using keyboard navigation. Because this is default behavior, I wouldn't recommend changing it (with JS, or something similar) due to the usability nightmare that would be created.

If this doesn't answer your question, please provide more details; Specifically, what exactly you're trying to accomplish

Comment: What if I had two different forms? Instead of two inputs and two search buttons?

Comment: @buildakicker That sort of change wouldn't give the ability for ENTER/RETURN to submit the form while a `<select>` is focused. If that is your goal, it's just not possible without hacking up some Javascript (as the easiest solution)

Comment: +1 ... though I'm not sure what he meant by the second part of his question regarding pressing enter is not firing the submit :-/

Comment: @Jack enter isn't submitting the second button, only the first.

Comment: Probably because Enter will use the first `type="submit"` button you have in your form by default ;-)